# Procedural Animated Winx Glitter (Confused With This Tutorial)

Tags: uv, shaders

I am following this tutorial on how to apply this animated glitter effect on my models, but sadly I am having a hard time understanding what the speaker in the video is saying. So I have been able to follow enough to build the actual UV Sphere but I am unsure of how to apply it to the Model.

I think he starts explaining how he does it at the 7:12 mark of this video but have a really hard time understanding what he says. I was hoping someone who knows what he is doing could help clarify things for me

[Link to Video Tutorial](https://youtu.be/kFYpWjE41H4?t=432)

[image]

Comment: It looks like he's just showing 2 different versions of the same shader. The second one (after 7:12) has an image texture with an alpha connected to the Principled BSDF, but the first shader does not. He's just showing you that you still have the option to connect an image texture, should you so choose.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this still. So Does this mean that both are able to apply to the model? What I want is to have an effect similar to how he shows in the first few seconds of the video when he gives his demonstration.

Comment: Yeah, if you look close at the "demo", you can see the model's skirt has a pattern on it - I think all the image texture does (that he shows connected after 7:12) is provide that pattern, the rest of the effect (stars and whatnot) is shown in the shader before the 7:12 mark

Comment: Ok, thank you but one last question. So Does he apply the shader to the model, or does it become visible on the model simply by having the UV Sphere over the model?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're separate - one for the sphere (no image), and one for the model (with image).